# chaining ExpressionEngine channel search paramaters AND or OR?

Tags: expressionengine

This code below:

```
{exp:channel:entries search:style="=ale" search:region="germany|belgium" search:rating="=3|4|5"}
```

Will it search for both region = (germany, or belgium) AND rating = (3, or 4, or 5)?  or is it an OR statement?

reason I ask is that I am trying to do a search where only entries display where they are NOT both matching.  i.e.

```
{exp:channel:entries search:style="=ale" search:region="= not belgium" search:rating="= not 5"}
```

meaning it will only display entries that are BOTH not belgium and not 5, if any entries are one but not the other, it still displays.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know there is a new EE focused Stack Exchange site now where you can post questions: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be "AND".  Remember that you get an exact match since you have `= not`.  Depending on your data you might (?) actually want just `not` for "does not contain".